# Unable to play DVD without admin rights - Win 10_1809 AD workstation

Tags: vlc-media-player, active-directory, windows-10-v1809

I'm running into an issue in VLC

When I go to open disk in VLC (Ctrl D) > DVD > Play. I get this error

"Playback failure:
DVDRead could not open the disc "F:".
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd:///F:\'. Check the log for details."

I'm posting the verbose logs from message below.

But when I open VLC with admin rights then it plays fine, 
Windows Enterprise 10_1809 Workstation is in an Active Directory Domain.

this is effecting multiple workstations with diffrent hardware configurations

Please can you help.

Thank You

> main debug: processing request item: dvd:///F:/, node: Playlist, skip:
>   0 main debug: rebuilding array of current - root Playlist main debug:
>   rebuild done - 2 items, index 1 main debug: starting playback of new
>   item main debug: resyncing on dvd:///F:/ main debug: dvd:///F:/ is at
>   1 main debug: creating new input thread main debug: Creating an input
>   for 'dvd:///F:/' main debug: requesting art for new input thread main
>   debug: using timeshift granularity of 50 MiB main debug: using
>   timeshift path: C:\Users\"USERNAME"\AppData\Local\Temp main debug:
>   `dvd:///F:/' gives access`dvd' demux `any' path`/F:/' main debug:
>   creating demux: access='dvd' demux='any' location='/F:/' file='F:\'
>   main debug: looking for access_demux module matching "dvd": 15
>   candidates main debug: looking for meta fetcher module matching "any":
>   1 candidates dvdnav warning: cannot open DVD (F:) dvdread error:
>   DVDRead cannot open source: F: lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in
>   C:\Users\"USERNAME"\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher main debug:
>   no access_demux modules matched main debug: creating access:
>   dvd:///F:/ main debug: (path: F:) main debug: looking for access
>   module matching "dvd": 26 candidates lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in
>   C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher main debug: no access
>   modules matched main debug: no meta fetcher modules matched main
>   debug: looking for art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates main
>   debug: dead input lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in
>   C:\Users\"USERNAME"\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art main debug:
>   changing item without a request (current 1/2) main debug: nothing to
>   play lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program
>   Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script
>   C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac lua
>   debug: skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program
>   Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac lua debug: Trying
>   Lua playlist script C:\Program
>   Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac lua debug:
>   skipping script (unmatched scope) C:\Program
>   Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac lua debug: Trying
>   Lua playlist script C:\Program
>   Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac lua debug: skipping
>   script (unmatched scope) C:\Program
>   Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac lua debug: Trying Lua
>   playlist script C:\Program
>   Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac lua debug: skipping
>   script (unmatched scope) C:\Program
>   Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac main debug: no art
>   finder modules matched main debug: looking for meta fetcher module
>   matching "any": 1 candidates lua debug: Trying Lua scripts in
>   C:\Users\"USERNAME"\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\fetcher lua debug:
>   Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\fetcher
>   main debug: no meta fetcher modules matched main debug: looking for
>   art finder module matching "any": 2 candidates lua debug: Trying Lua
>   scripts in C:\Users\"USERNAME"\AppData\Roaming\vlc\lua\meta\art lua
>   debug: Trying Lua scripts in C:\Program
>   Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art lua debug: Trying Lua playlist script
>   C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\00_musicbrainz.luac lua
>   debug: Trying Lua playlist script C:\Program
>   Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\01_googleimage.luac lua debug: Trying
>   Lua playlist script C:\Program
>   Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\02_frenchtv.luac lua debug: Trying Lua
>   playlist script C:\Program
>   Files\VideoLAN\VLC\lua\meta\art\03_lastfm.luac main debug: no art
>   finder modules matched

Comment: Is it only VLC? Can you copy the files from the DVD using Explorer?

Comment: @MichaelFrank You gave me the idea, I found a workaround, it works thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found that worked for me was either opening VLC with Admin Rights or first browsing the DVD drive in Windows Explorer (“Open”) and then on the VIDEO_TS folder > “Play with VLC”

Thank You all for your help.

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with VLC Mediaplayer 32-bit 3.0.71 (also tried 64-bit) on WIN 10 Pro Build 17763.

Playback failure:
DVDRead could not open the disc "I:".
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'dvd:///I:/'. Check the log for details.
dvdread error: DVDRead cannot open source: I:

Running VLC with admin right also worked for me. Tried different DVD drives and different DVDs.

Comment: After updating Windows to 1903 running VLC and watching DVDs works fine without admin priviliges.

Comment: After installing new Updates on 1903 the problem is back again. Watching DVDs only works when its openend with admin rights!